# ¿Que método o herramienta puedo utilizar para evaluar dos piezas de código y saber cual tiene un mejor rendimiento?

Tags: javascript, rendimiento

Tengo dos piezas de código en javascript y quiero saber con exactitud cual se ejecuta mas rápido. ¿ que puedo utilizar para obtener esa información ?

Comment: Añade tu codigo a la pregunta,  agrega dos timer para la ejecucion antes y despues. //ejemplo    console.time("factorial test");

for (var i = 1; i < 100000; i++) {
    factorial(20);
}

console.timeEnd("factorial test");
// => 512.46ms tiempo total

Comment: En Chrome abre el inspector y haz click en le pestaña `Performance`. La decisión tendrá que ser tuya: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/